# Azure Function Precompile deploy

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a C# Precompiled Azure function project that I would like to deploy from VS. While the .funproj (the azure function project) deploys normally, the required dlls are not uploaded.

Is there some way of getting those deployed together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently that is a limitation of the .funproj format.

Here's a link to suggest support for precompiled: 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/17709979-visual-studio-tooling-for-precompiled-functions

However, there's a relatively easy workaround: instead of using the functions project, use an aspnet project, which allows you to `right click project -> publish` to your function app. I've attached an example showing the structure of an aspnet project with three functions.

For more details on this approach, see https://aka.ms/precompiled-functions.

[image: precompiled functions aspnet project]

Comment: Thanks! Will this be deployable to a regular web app also?